# How to solve $\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,1)}\frac{4x-y+5}{(1+2x+y)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have a limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(-1,1)}\frac{4x-y+5}{(1+2x+y)^2}$$

Is my solution correct? If not, what is step by step solution for this limit? Thank you.

**My solution:**

I replaced $y$ with $k(x^2+1)+1$.

$$\lim_{x\to-1\\y=k(x^2+1)+1}\frac{4x-(k(x^2+1)+1)+5}{(1+2x+(k(x^2+1)+1))^2}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{4x-kx^2-k+4}{(2x+kx^2+k+2)^2}=\frac{-4-k-k+4}{(-2+k+k+2)^2}=\frac{-2k}{4k^2}$$

Limit depends on $k$ so limit does not exist.

Comment: If we plug in $x=-1$ in $k(x^2+1)+1$, we get $2k+1$ ... Try $y=k(x+1)+1$

Comment: Then I've got 0/0. Is that means I should use different aproach?

Comment: When you choose the path $\;y=k(x^2+1)+1\;$, you get that if $\;x\to-1\;$ then $\;y\to2k+1\;$ , which isn't $\;1\;$ **unless** $\;k=0\;$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate variables with substitution it **must be** that on that particular pat you approach the wanted point... For example, take $\;y=k(x+1)+1\;$ (observe that $\;x\to-1\;\implies\;y\to1\;$, as required), so the limit is

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{4x-kx-k-1+5}{(1+2x+kx+k+1)^2}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{(4-k)(x+1)}{(2+k)^2(x+1)^2}=\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{4-k}{(2+k)^2(x+1)}$$

and the last limit doesn't even exist finitely, so the original one neither does.

Comment: Isn't $(2x+kx+k+2)^2$ equals to $(2+k)^2(x+1)^2$ instead of $(2+k)(x+1)$?

Comment: @user428015 Indeed so, and I'm going to correct that now, thanks...yet thart makes it even clearer the limit cannot exist! :)